# Parsing nested HTML Custom tags with RegEx in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am working in javascript to manipulate an html block of code stored in a string. The test case I'm using looks like this:

```
    '<iteration array = "Team1.TeamMembers" > \n' +
            '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
            '<iteration array = "Team2.TeamMembers" > \n' +
                  '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
                  '<iteration array = "Team3.TeamMembers" > \n' +
                       '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
                  '</iteration> \n' +
                  '<iteration array = "Team5.TeamMembers" > \n' +
                       '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
                  '</iteration> \n' +
            '</iteration> \n' +
    '</iteration> \n' +
    '<iteration array = "Team4.TeamMembers" > \n' +
            '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
     '</iteration> \n' +
     '</ul> \n';
```

The array and the placeholders would be taken from a json file given as input, but they are irrelevant to the problem I'm having. I need to correctly identify the nesting level of each custom html tag in order to properly replace each placeholder and variable. I tried several regex solutions, but they all eventually break on some level. I *know* that I'm not supposed to use regex to parse html, but this is the task I'm supposed to solve. Any suggestions or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a custom parser. Regex alone is *very bad* for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent wheel - there is a parser already [DOMParser documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).
It parse code as HTML page including head, etc., but you can find what you want then and existing properties may be accessed directly, but non-existing probably explicitly too:

```js
var src = '<iteration array = "Team1.TeamMembers" > \n' +
            '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
            '<iteration array = "Team2.TeamMembers" > \n' +
                  '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
                  '<iteration array = "Team3.TeamMembers" > \n' +
                       '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
                  '</iteration> \n' +
                  '<iteration array = "Team5.TeamMembers" > \n' +
                       '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
                  '</iteration> \n' +
            '</iteration> \n' +
    '</iteration> \n' +
    '<iteration array = "Team4.TeamMembers" > \n' +
            '<li> {Name} </li> \n' +
     '</iteration> \n' +
     '</ul> \n';
var parser = new DOMParser(), dom;
dom = parser.parseFromString(src, "text/html");
dom = dom.documentElement.lastElementChild.firstElementChild; // body -> iteration
console.log( dom.getAttribute("array") );
```

Answer (score -1):

With some preformatting you can turn it into valid xml (remove whitespace/linebreaks add a starting ul-open-tag):

```xml
<ul>
    <iteration array="Team1.TeamMembers">
        <li>{Name}</li>
        <iteration array="Team2.TeamMembers">
            <li>{Name}</li>
            <iteration array="Team3.TeamMembers">
                <li>{Name}</li>
            </iteration>
            <iteration array="Team5.TeamMembers">
                <li>{Name}</li>
            </iteration>
        </iteration>
    </iteration>
    <iteration array="Team4.TeamMembers">
        <li>{Name}</li>
    </iteration>
</ul>
```

from that you can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the Document.

Comment: This is not an answer. Why do you rewrite OP?